# Help with solving the DistributionNotFound error in Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I've installed `virtualenv` on my system which the argument to not copy over any site packages. Then I did an `easy_install` to install Django and that went fine too.

In the virtual environ when i try and try `django-admin.py`, I get an error that I'm not being able to resolve. Could someone help me out please? Thanks a ton.

```
(virt1) C:\virt_env\virt1>Scripts\django-admin.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virt_env\virt1\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Program_Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2607, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "C:\Program_Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: django==1.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `easy_install` knows about `virtualenv`. Use `pip` instead.